# What's the difference between indeterminacy and explosiveness in the context of dynamic systems?

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-dynamics, steady-state

One important question to ask is if the model has as unique stable (asymptotically stationary) solution (determinacy) or multiple solutions (indeterminacy).

But what's the difference between indeterminacy and explosiveness in the context of dynamic systems?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Neither *indeterminacy* nor *explosiveness* are established terms. Please [edit] your question to clarify what you mean by those (or what definition you were given).

Comment: George W. Evans, Seppo Honkapohja - Learning and Expectations in Macroeconomics (Frontiers of Economic Research)-Princeton University Press (2001)

constantly use these terms, without really explaining them.


It's available on google books for free (most pages).

Comment: Then I suggest you first ask a question about what *explosiveness* means. After a quick glance, I have an idea, but then it is a term primarily used by those who study AR processes, so somebody else is probably better suited to answer this than me.

Comment: ok will do, thx